# How to add menus in magento frontend

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm new to magento and I m trying to display the menus on frontend in magento but I don't
  know the steps how to add menus can anyone guide me as I m new to magento.

Thanks in advance

Comment: menu for categories ?

Answer (score 0):

In general the term menu refers to the category navigation in magento. SO as i understand, you want to create categories and subcategories of the products that you are going to create in magento. SO for creating main category and their sub category follow these links http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-and-managing-categories . Let me know if u have doubts.